# Help needed with weird corner issue in prusa slicer

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-cura, prusaslicer

I've been dealing with 3D printing for a few weeks now. I'm trying to figure what is wrong with my print sliced in PrusaSlicer. Here's how the filleted bottom of my cube should look like:

[image]

Now, this is how it turns out, sliced with PrusaSlicer:

[image]

and here's how Cura does it, not a perfection but much closer to the required:

[image]

I'm printing on an Ender3 S1 Pro with Klipper, 0.4@nbsp;mm, pressure advance and input shaping calibrated. Both slicers are roughly the same settings: 0.2@nbsp;mm, 130@nbsp;mm/s inner perimeters, 100@nbsp;mm/s outer ones. I want to be using PrusaSlicer for it has some special features compared to Cura.

The same cube without a fillet, turns out absolute perfection.

Comment: Does PrusaSlicer have different layer heights set for that corner?